# Cannot use Scrapy in Python 3.5 on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, scrapy, twisted

I have `Scrapy` installed through Anaconda3 with **Python 3.5** in **Windows 8.1**. When i tried to import Scrapy, it made the following error:

> File "C:...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\compat.py", line 745, in 
>      Version("Twisted", 15, 5, 0),
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

What does that error mean?

I've read some pages on 2016 said that Scrapy can't be used on Windows with **Python 3**, but maybe there are many improvements and tricks I don't know of. Should I downgrade my Python to **2.7** to use Scrapy?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#what-python-versions-does-scrapy-support) suggests that Scrapy should work on Py 3+. Does this error occur on the import line?

Comment: Try creating a new virtual environment and then try installing scrapy inside that

Comment: Are you on the latest Twisted version? If not update using `conda update twisted` because there were some issues with earlier versions of Twisted and Scrapy. I believe everything is working now, at least I don't have any issues with Py3.6, Twisted, and Scrapy.